# xap file download location

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-2.0, xap

When I connect to a web-site that is using Silverlight, my understanding is that the "XAP" file is downloaded to `C:\Users\ "UserName" \AppData\Local\Temp` folder (under windows Vista).

There are few sites that I know that are using "XAP" files but I don't see a "XAP" file in this folder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer. It just gets downloaded to the logged-in user's temporary internet files folder.

Comment: hi TreeUK, I have same issue but can not find xap file in user's temporary files folder as well.